# Compilation error: size of array element is not a multiple of its alignment

Tags: gcc, mpich, gcc11

I am trying to compile MPICH 3.2 with GCC 11.3.1 in Rocky Linux 9 and I am getting multiple times the following error:

`error: size of array element is not a multiple of its alignment`

In the MPICH mailing list somebody solves it compiling with GCC 10 (https://lists.mpich.org/pipermail/discuss/2021-December/006318.html), but I would like to know if it is possible to continue with GCC 11 enabling some flag or via any other solution, since not always is possible to have an specific version of the software.